# filepicker.io webhook not happening

Tags: filepicker.io

I setup a webhook in filepicker.io's webhook page, saved the url (e.g., mydomain.com/upload-hook) and I proceed to upload a file and tail the log files watching for any request to this node endpoint where I immediately console.log the request object to see if it is from filepicker.io, but nothing.

I even try using curl to get the status of my file uploads and it is saying "File Not Found" using something like this:

curl -X GET https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/My_API_Key/video_convert/status?uuid=22ae147492ab72a0a3cb110a4d0046cd

Really need some hints on this if anyone can help! Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the status of your video, you need **use the filelink, not your API key** (same thing applies to the first POST action that starts conversion process). For example, if the file you want to convert is

`https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zVlc5jEJQhWQFABCDEFG`

first you need to do:

```
curl -X POST "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zVlc5jEJQhWQFABCDEFG/video_convert?height=260&width=300&preset=webm"
```

You'll receive a response looking like this:

```
{"uuid":"ff18d687bd34c9c03bb303b585512345","timestamp":"1434359559","data":{},"status":"started"}
```

To check conversion status:

```
curl -X GET "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/zVlc5jEJQhWQFABCDEFG/video_convert/status?uuid=ff18d687bd34c9c03bb303b585512345"
```

I did a test using requestb.in to create my webhook url and I received a webhook when my video was converted.

Please let me know if this helps.